# Undefined control sequence in equation environment

Tags: equations

I like to have the equation

> Path={Path_i} where 1 ≤ i ≤ k, k = Total number of paths.
> **i will be in subscript

I have used the following code under equation environment

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{path}
Path={Path_i}, where 1\leqslant i \leqslant k, k = Total number of paths
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But the above error is coming. What is wrong with the syntax?

> tried with \mathrm and $ without equation environment and also with [].

Comment: Loading `amssymb` and replacing `svjour3` with `article` the code works fine. Try these steps first.

Comment: ok, loading amssymb solved the problem. I thought amsmath includes symbols also. Beginner's mistake. Thanks Ivan. Is there anyway to introduce gap within the entities in the equation other than manually inserting ~ ?

Comment: Anyway, the text part is typeset math mode, e.g. `number` is *not* the product of the six variables n,u,m,b, e and r. You the `\text{…}`  command for that.

Comment: @Bernard How is this suggestion related to my query?

Comment: It is totally independent. I just proposed to improve the result. Also, you mention ‘the above error’ but it is not in your post.